# Adaboost for numeric dataset

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, ensemble-learning, adaboost

I have been trying to fit Adaboost to work with continuous valued data set and the more I read the more I keep getting confused. I have read about the multiclass Adaboost with log(K-1) addition to alpha, but is it enough contidion to handle continuous values?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean by "is it enough"? Enough to have read about "multiclass..." ? Are you just asking if it's possible to use Adaboost with continuous data?

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I have edited the answer.Yes, I am trying to adapt Adaboost to work with regression(continuous) data.

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer in [Continuous Multistate Ada-boost method?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23358/continuous-multistate-ada-boost-method). The SAMME adaboost method for multistate labels that you mention adds $log(K-1)$ to the $\alpha_t$ term used to weight the pts in the feature space for the next step. It is used for multistate problems. I don't think there is a version of adaboost for data with labels in $R$ as the alogrithm relies fundamentally on the exponential loss $e^{(-yx)}$ which just doesn't work for continuous data.

You should try to partition the label space as coarsely as you can and use SAMME (multiclass discrete adaboost).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have read about this article, but my values are independent. I have also read about mapping regression into classification with the equal width method. But I just do not understand when I have the partitioned data lets say my data is partitioned in 3 intervals {1.2, 1,3 ,2} {6.5, 6.9 ,8.1} {10,5, 11,3 ,15} . How is each of this intervals represented in the actual algorithm?

Comment: If your label falls in the first interval, the label is replaced with 0. Ditto for 1,2. The algorithm now finds a predictor that attempts to determine which interval your data will fall into. The setup here involves you knowing the intervals beforehand.

Comment: If we assume that my three intervals are {0...5}, {6....10} and {10...15} representing the above values in each, how will Adaboost know in which interval will the label fall into? The final hypothesis is just a sign, or here we take the max value?

Comment: Relabel your data to reflect the states $\{0,1,2\}$ before running the SAMME algorithm. Run it on the relabeled data. You will generate an estimator which will predict a state 0,1,2 for a data point.